# Sum of diagonal products

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to get the sumproduct but only for specific diagonals in an array. My setup is like below and the yellow highlighting should give an idea of how the formula should calculate

[image]

*As text:*

```
Years   Rates       0   1   2   3
25  0.16        25  24  23  22
26  0.11        26  25  24  23
27  0.12        27  26  25  24
28  0.13        28  27  26  25
29  0.17        29  28  27  26
30  0.16        30  29  28  27


Years   Sum of products                 
25                      
26                      
27                      
28                      
29                      
30
```

Note, the table on the right dictates how many years to include, so if the table were extended to include 4 years then `0.17*4` would need to be included in the sum product for `25`

What is the best way to do this? Ideally not a CSE formula/ VBA. The actual table is much bigger, so I might need to be conscious of speed too.

I intend to edit this with what I came up with but I hope to see some different ways of doing this so I hope it's okay that I hold off for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way I can find, without using a CSE formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:$F$7=$A11),$B$2:$B$7*$C$1:$F$1)
```

> The first array is `n x m` in size and the second array is the product
>   of a `n x 1` and `1 x m` array, which is converted to an `n x m`
>   array. This provides `SUMPRODUCT` with two identically sized arrays as required.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

`=MMULT(G4:J4,B7:B10)`

Regards

Comment: I don't think this drags down nicely, or actually gives the `sum` ?

Comment: Define how you would like it to "drag down nicely". Of course it gives the sum!

Comment: Ah, I see - yes it does return the sum (I usually expect to see an array with `MMULT` but it happens to be 1x1 in this case so no need to `SUM`). But when I drag down I get errors from 28 years onwards - keeping `G4:J4` absolute

Comment: When you copy my formula (with your correction for absolute referencing to G4:J4) down one row, it becomes =MMULT($G$4:$J$4,B8:B11). Is this not what you want? If so, what do you want?

Comment: I need to be able to fill out the table in my example (the empty cells below the *Sum of products* heading) so I need to be able to drag it down 6 times in the example - many more in reality. The formula breaks after you drag it down a few times - when there are empty values in column B

Comment: If empty cells are a problem, change it to: =MMULT($G$4:$J$4,0+B7:B10)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of that as a *fix* simply because if I have 0-80 years across the top then I need 80 blank cells below the bottom of my table in column B - if anyone were to put some text there it would throw errors

Comment: So text entries are a possibility as well as blanks?

Comment: Consider age 29: it should just be `0.17*0 + 0.16*1` rather than `0.17*0 + 0.16*1 + ?*2 + ?*3... etc`. By letting your ranges fall off the bottom of the table I don't want to end up with unexpected errors

Answer (score 0):

You could give this CSE a try, maybe it's not as bad (even though you don't want one)

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(B7:B10,TRANSPOSE(G4:J4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a 'CSE' formula will be best even though you'd prefer not to.

With the first formula in B11 and the setup as in your image, (with the 0, 1, 2, 3 in D1:G1, the word "Rates" in B1, and the array in D2:G7 etc)

```
{=SUM(IF($D$2:$G$7=A11, $D$1:$G$1*$B$2:$B$7, 0))}
```

and drag down